# Android Performance Issue- TabHost - Timer - SetCurrentTab() - Google Maps Api V2

Tags: android, timer, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-maps-v2

As i said in title i 've got a performance issue on my Android application. I've got a public static **tabhost** and a **timer** and a **Google Maps**. Timer scheduled to work every 3 seconds. It 's updating something according to my **WebService** which is related to database.

For example if my web service **response equals to "1" then i'm switching tab 0 otherwise 1.** In this case when i switch to google maps which is in tab 1 with this update everything is ok. **When a second update came with a result of "0" i'm setting current tab to 0**. In this tab, activity performance is ok. Then i entered subactivities which placed on this tab everything is ok again. **But when i'm trying to go back with "Back" button it costs me for 3 or 4 seconds to go back (to tab 0)**

What's wrong with that ?

```
                    if(response.equals("1"))
                    {
                        if(CTSMainActivity.tabHost.getCurrentTab()!=0)
                            CTSMainActivity.tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
                    }
                    else if(response.equals("0"))
                    {
                        if(CTSMainActivity.tabHost.getCurrentTab()!=1)
                            CTSMainActivity.tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
                    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit :**

I just googled for it and got something. **I used DDMS method profiling tool** and saw **android/widget/Listview.measureHeightofChildren(IIII)I**  process is using 3.7 seconds. What 's the solution of it ?

**Edit :**

**I kinda find a solution please follow this link : [Android - Remove Google Maps Fragment onPause and add back onResume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263408/android-remove-google-maps-fragment-onpause-and-add-back-onresume)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue with removing tabHost. And using activities with **new Intent();** Please refer this url : [Android - Remove Google Maps Fragment onPause and add back onResume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263408/android-remove-google-maps-fragment-onpause-and-add-back-onresume)