# Android - Remove Google Maps Fragment onPause and add back onResume

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, onresume, onpause

I need to remove Google map fragment on Activity onPause event and add it back onResume event. How can i do this ?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Accordingly to this [Back button very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827949/android-back-button-very-slow)**

**Need it for [Android Performance Issue- TabHost - Timer - SetCurrentTab() - Google Maps Api V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262328/android-performance-issue-tabhost-timer-setcurrenttab-google-maps-api-v)**

**Edit :**

**Actually I did it. But still got a delay problem. How can i stop/close intents at back stack?**

**Edit :**

**Also i'm now trying to remove and add back fragment please see this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275349/android-add-supportfragment-and-get-it-back-from-its-tag-null**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just removed tabview. It's really fast now.If you are worrying about performance in a situation like mine, I suggest you to remove tabhost and just use **new Intent().**

Comment: I have a question how do you remove the tabhost?

Comment: just replacing it with Activities, one for loading and many for tabs.

Comment: What do you mean do you have an example.

Comment: sorry i can't explain it with example but basicly i mean just remove the TabHost control and work with only Activites.